# ANTLR 4.5.2 not recognizing Number token

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

I'm trying to parse the string "define one: 1." with the following simple demo class:

```
public class ANTLRDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        AremelleLexer lexer = new AremelleLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("define one: 1."));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        AremelleParser parser = new AremelleParser(tokens);
        ProgramContext p = parser.program();
    }
}
```

However, I keep running into this error message:

> line 1:12 mismatched input '1' expecting {'define', '{', Identifier, Number, String}

The relevant grammar is:

```
DIGIT
:   '0'..'9'
;

Integer
:   DIGIT+
;

Number
:   Integer (DOT Integer)?
;
```

Why is "1" not being recognized as a Number?

An interesting note is that the string "define one: 1.0." parses fine, so ANTLR is able to recognize numbers with decimal points, but not integers without decimal points.

Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lexer rules are ambiguous.

`1` is a token which can be matched by *all* of your rules: `DIGIT`, `Integer` and `Number`. Note that all 3 of them are lexer rules since their name starts with an uppercase letter.

To disambiguate, ANTLR first chooses the longest token which can match a rule, and when several rules are left, it choses the *first one*.

So in your case, `1` yields a `DIGIT` token, but your grammar expects a `Number`, as the error message says.

I *think* what you intended to do is to use *fragments*, which aren't standalone lexer rules but reusable grammar parts:

```
fragment DIGIT
:   '0'..'9'
;

fragment INTEGER
:   DIGIT+
;

NUMBER
:   Integer (DOT Integer)?
;
```

With this grammar, all your numbers will always be of the `NUMBER` token type.

Comment: However, what should I do if some other lexer rule specifically requires an INTEGER but not a NUMBER?

Comment: You could resolve this with parser rules instead. Something like `number : INTEGER | FLOAT; integer: INTEGER;`, or accept a `NUMBER` and validate the value in a second step (you should do that anyway since `INTEGER` could be much larger than what would fit into 32 bits).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again.